# how to add script in controller in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a admin.js and admin.css file. I have to include it inside admin.php that is a controller. because that would be better to include that js and css in perticular module instead of adding it in header.php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add it in the corresponding `view` for that `controller` imo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built in CodeIginiter function to include this output like there is for CSS using the link_tag() function provided by CI. I've added a function called script_tag() to the system/helpers/html_helper.php file from CI. The function is:

```
if ( ! function_exists('script_tag')) {
    function script_tag($src = '', $language = 'javascript', $type = 'text/javascript', $index_page = FALSE)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $script = '<scr'.'ipt';
        if (is_array($src)) {
            foreach ($src as $k=>$v) {
                if ($k == 'src' AND strpos($v, '://') === FALSE) {
                    if ($index_page === TRUE) {
                        $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->site_url($v).'"';
                    }
                    else {
                        $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->slash_item('base_url').$v.'"';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $script .= "$k=\"$v\"";
                }
            }

            $script .= "></scr"."ipt>\n";
        }
        else {
            if ( strpos($src, '://') !== FALSE) {
                $script .= ' src="'.$src.'" ';
            }
            elseif ($index_page === TRUE) {
                $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->site_url($src).'" ';
            }
            else {
                $script .= ' src="'.$CI->config->slash_item('base_url').$src.'" ';
            }

            $script .= 'language="'.$language.'" type="'.$type.'"';
            $script .= ' /></scr'.'ipt>'."\n";
        }
        return $script;
    }
}
```

Then in your PHP code you can do:

echo script_tag('content/js/jquery-1.4.2.js');

Comment: never edit files in `system\helpers` directory. add `MY_` suffix to file name and add file to `application\helpers`. Also, check out [**script_tag() for CodeIgniter**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/CIScriptTag)

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about how to include js/css just like what the link tag does?

```
    class Admin extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct(){
             parent::__construct();
        }
        public function index(){
             $this->template->add_css('path_to_css/admin.css',TRUE);
             $this->template->add_js('path_to_js/admin.js',TRUE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including script file in controller you can include script file in view page.

For example :

View page : Test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../application/js/validator.inc.js"></script>
<div>
//your code
</div>
```

Hope this will help you... :)